# PL/pgSQL function to randomly select an id

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Goal:

1. pre-populate a table with a list of sequential id, from e.g. 1 to 1,000,000.  The table has an additional column that is nillable.  NULL values are marked as *unassigned* and non-NULL values are marked as *assigned*
2. have function i can call that asks for `x` number of randomly chosen ids from the table which have not been assigned.

This is for something quite specific and while I understand there are different ways of doing this, I'd like to know if there's a solution to the flaw in this particular implementation.

I have something that partially works, but wondering where the flaw in the function is.

Here's the table:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE accounts_seq MINVALUE 700000000001 NO MAXVALUE;

CREATE TABLE accounts (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY default nextval('accounts_seq'), 
  client VARCHAR(25), UNIQUE(id, client)
);
```

This function `gen_account_ids` is just a one-time setup to pre-populate the table with a fixed number of rows, all marked as *unassigned*.

```
/*
  This function will insert new rows into the accounts table with ids being
  generated by a sequence, and client being NULL.  A NULL client indicates
  the account has not yet been assigned.
*/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gen_account_ids(bigint)
  RETURNS INT AS $gen_account_ids$
DECLARE
  -- count is the number of new accounts you want generated
  count alias for $1;
  -- rowcount is returned as the number of rows inserted
  rowcount int;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO accounts(client) SELECT NULL FROM generate_series(1, count);
  GET DIAGNOSTICS rowcount = ROW_COUNT;
  RETURN rowcount;
END;
$gen_account_ids$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

So, I use this to pre-populate the table with, say 1000 records:

```
SELECT gen_account_ids(1000);
```

The next function `assign` is meant to randomly select an *unassigned* id (unassigned means `client` column is null), and update it with a client value so it becomes assigned.  It returns the number of rows affected.

It works *sometimes*, but I do believe there are collisions occurring -- which is why I tried for `DISTINCT`, but it often returns fewer than the desired number of rows.  For example, if I `select assign(100, 'foo');` it might return 95 rows instead of the desired 100.

How can I modify this to make it always return the exact desired rows?

```
   /*
     This will assign ids to a client randomly
     @param int is the number of account numbers to generate
     @param varchar(10) is a string descriptor for the client
     @returns the number of rows affected -- should be the same as the input int

     Call it like this: `SELECT * FROM assign(100, 'FOO')`
   */
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION assign(INT, VARCHAR(10))
     RETURNS INT AS $$
   DECLARE
     total ALIAS FOR $1;
     clientname ALIAS FOR $2;
     rowcount int;
   BEGIN
     UPDATE accounts SET client = clientname WHERE id IN (
       SELECT DISTINCT trunc(random() * (
         (SELECT max(id) FROM accounts WHERE client IS NULL) - 
         (SELECT min(id) FROM accounts WHERE client IS NULL)) + 
         (SELECT min(id) FROM accounts WHERE client IS NULL)) FROM generate_series(1, total));
     GET DIAGNOSTICS rowcount = ROW_COUNT;
     RETURN rowcount;
   END;
   $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This is loosely based on [this](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/postgresql-select-a-random-number-in-a-range-between-two-numbers/) where you can do something like `SELECT trunc(random() * (100 - 1) + 1) FROM generate_series(1,5);` which will select 5 random numbers between 1 and 100.

My goal is to do something similar where I select a random id between the min and max unassigned rows, and mark it for update.

Comment: Relevant blog: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/tablesample-and-other-methods-for-getting-random-tuples/

Comment: @CraigRinger thx! TABLESAMPLE looks really cool!  not sure if it'll work for me or not, but there's a lot of good info on that blog...investigating.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the best answer b/c it does involve full table scans, but in my situation, I'm not concerned about the performance, and it works.  This is based off @CraigRinger's reference to the blog post [getting random tuples](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/tablesample-and-other-methods-for-getting-random-tuples/)

I'd be generally interested in hearing about other (perhaps better) solutions -- and am specifically curious about why the original solution falls short, and what @klin also devised.

So, here's my brute force random order solution:

```
-- generate a million unassigned rows with null client column
insert into accounts(client) select null from generate_series(1, 1000000);

-- assign 1000 random rows to client 'foo'
update accounts set client = 'foo' where id in 
  (select id from accounts where client is null order by random() limit 1000);
```

Comment: I think this solution is the best and most natural for sql. Do not worry about performance as the possible alternatives should be equally or more expensive. You can calmly accept your answer (and thank Craig).

Comment: Thanks klin -- I appreciate the time you took to investigate and offer some solutions.  Thanks also @CraigRinger for the link -- lots of good info on that blog.  If you want to submit an answer, I'll accept that one if you want the karma.  I can't accept my own answer until 19 hrs have passed.

Answer (score 1):

Because `ids` of random subset of rows are not consecutive, select a random `row_number()` instead of random `id`.

```
with nulls as ( -- base query
    select id
    from accounts 
    where client is null
    ),
randoms as ( -- calculate random int in range 1..count(nulls.*) 
    select trunc(random()* (count(*) - 1) + 1)::int random_value
    from nulls
    ),
row_numbers as ( -- add row numbers to nulls
    select id, row_number() over (order by id) rn
    from nulls
    )
select id
from row_numbers, randoms
where rn = random_value; -- random row number
```

A function is not necessary here, but you can easily place the query in a function body if needed.

This query updates 5 random rows with null `client`.

```
update accounts
set client = 'new value' -- <-- clientname
where id in (
    with nulls as ( -- base query
        select id
        from accounts 
        where client is null
        ),
    randoms as ( -- calculate random int in range 1..count(nulls.*) 
        select i, trunc(random()* (count(*) - 1) + 1)::int random_value
        from nulls
        cross join generate_series(1, 5) i -- <--  total
        group by 1
        ),
    row_numbers as ( -- add row numbers to nulls in order by id
        select id, row_number() over (order by id) rn
        from nulls
        )
    select id
    from row_numbers, randoms
    where rn = random_value -- random row number
)
```

However, there is no certainty that the query will update exactly 5 rows, because

```
select trunc(random()* (max_value - 1) + 1)::int
from generate_series(1, n)
```

is **not** a correct way to generate `n` different random values. The probability of repetitions increases with the quotient `n / max_value`.

Comment: Thanks @klin -- that does indeed generate a single unique id.  I guess the reason I was defining as a function was it would be used periodically to generate, i.e. *assign* a set of random ids for some `x` total.  For example, assign 100 random ids, assign 1000 random ids.  My next step was to look at using window functions.  I'll see if I can try to incorporate this into assigning multiple random ids for some total `x`

Comment: Ah, I spoke too soon.  It does indeed suffer from the same problem my solution above does.  See https://gist.github.com/davisford/dcec6dfe58f3a17aa1b7